# How to populate a selection list with a member from each object in an array list of objects?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, awt, jlist

I have a class (built like a struct) for colors that I am loading in through a file:

```
public class ColorData
{
    public String name;
    public int r;
    public int g;
    public int b;
}
```

I am using a JList, and I would populate it with just "name" of the ColorData. I have found how to populate it with [arrays or vectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html). I also found a solution that would take the arraylist and turn it into an array. I'm not sure how that would work with my arraylist of my ColorData Object. I need to use this so that the program will work with the numbers (r, b, and g) when the color name is selected.

Comment: 1) Provide a `toString()` method to `ColorData` that returns `name` or.. 2) Use a renderer for the list of `ColorData` objects that renders the `name`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

```
public class ColorData
{
    public String name;
    public int r;
    public int g;
    public int b;
}
```

Above is the ColorData class that I used. Then I created a function that I called populate_saved_list. This is a function that created an ArrayList of Strings. Then I went through each original ArrayList of the ColorData and added the name to the ArrayLists of Strings. Then I used the JList's built in function of setListData( E[] listData ) and the ArrayList's build in function of toArray().

```
private void populate_saved_list (ArrayList<ColorData> allColors, JList colorList)
{
    ArrayList<String> colorNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < allColors.size(); i++ )
    {
        colorNames.add(allColors.get(i).name);
    }

    colorList.setListData(colorNames.toArray());
}
```